# How to sync time in app with current time? (WindowsPhone, C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.1. The time in the app has to be synchronized mostly exact with the current time. Let's say the server is sync with this [exact time](http://time.is/). So how can I get my app to have the same time as the server? I don't want to bother my users setting their phones time or change the time of the phone.

What I have is this `Int32 unixTimestamp`:

**C#**

```
Int32 unixTimestamp = 
    (Int32)(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds;
```

This timestamp gives for example `1459500000` but the server gives `1459500030`. 
Do I have to go online and get the time there or is there a better solution to do this in the app itselfs?

All help appreciated.

---

*Notice, the phone and the server are in the same timezone when I'm developing, but if possible I want to do this trick for all timezones at once. Do this timestamp change when I'm in another timezone? As @Sharp said, the unixtimestamp is the same in all timezones*

Comment: Unix timestamp never changes, and you don't have to sanitize for timezones as it's always in UTC. If you however need that time to be in UTC+2, then you need to align it with your timezone. As the "timezone alignment" can be done last, dont worry about it for now.

Comment: Are you saying that you want your app's version of the current time to be thirty seconds off the phone's version?

Comment: Ok thanks @Shark, I will edit this in the post.

Comment: @RowlandShaw, no thats the case with the phone in this case, I want them perfectly aligned (max 5 seconds off)

Comment: Unix timestamp actually has no knowledge of timezones :/ But since we do, we can help it to perfectly match our needs with a few workarounds which I posted for you ;) Basically you just need to 'translate' that UTC time to your UTC+x timezone as a last step and you'll be fine.

Comment: So you're wanting to set the phone's internal clock?

Comment: Nope, I just want to use the same time as the server in my app.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that can help you, however it's not in C#.

```
/**
 * Converts the given <code>date</code> from the <code>fromTimeZone</code> to the
 * <code>toTimeZone</code>.  Since java.util.Date has does not really store time zome
 * information, this actually converts the date to the date that it would be in the
 * other time zone.
 *
 * @param date
 * @param fromTimeZone
 * @param toTimeZone
 * @return
 */
public static Date convertTimeZone(Date date, TimeZone fromTimeZone, TimeZone toTimeZone) {
    long fromTimeZoneOffset = getTimeZoneUTCAndDSTOffset(date, fromTimeZone);
    long toTimeZoneOffset = getTimeZoneUTCAndDSTOffset(date, toTimeZone);

    return new Date(date.getTime() + (toTimeZoneOffset - fromTimeZoneOffset));
}

/**
 * Calculates the offset of the <code>timeZone</code> from UTC, factoring in any
 * additional offset due to the time zone being in daylight savings time as of
 * the given <code>date</code>.
 *
 * @param date
 * @param timeZone
 * @return
 */
private static long getTimeZoneUTCAndDSTOffset(Date date, TimeZone timeZone) {
    long timeZoneDSTOffset = 0;
    if (timeZone.inDaylightTime(date)) {
        timeZoneDSTOffset = timeZone.getDSTSavings();
    }

    return timeZone.getRawOffset() + timeZoneDSTOffset;
}
```

Here's a sample of how it's used:

```
/**
 *The method to set the start of the <i>Estimated Delivery Time</i> window<br>
 * Internally calls {@link #updateRedzoneDrawable}
 * @param startTime the start of the EstimatedDeliveryTime window
 */
public void setEstimatedDeliveryTimeFrom(Date startTime) {
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "---> setEstimatedDeliveryTimeFrom(" + startTime + ")");
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "startTime = " + startTime + "\tstartTime.getHours() = " + startTime.getHours() + ", startTime.getMinutes() = " + startTime.getMinutes());
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "formatted startTime = " + formatter.format(startTime));

    Date newStartTime = convertTimeZone(startTime, TimeZone.getDefault(), TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Log.d(LOGTAG, "expectedDelivery_start = newStartTime (" + newStartTime + ")");
    expectedDelivery_start = newStartTime;

    updateRedzoneDrawable();
}
```

I hope you guys don't downvote me to infinity for posting Java code in a C# thread, but I'm doing so to help you because [Date](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)s work with just Unix timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need an API call to query your server for it's time (you'll need to make some assumptions based on the latency), and compare that to your local time.

You've said that you don't want to set the phone's internal clock to match, so your only other option is to use the comparison in difference between the server time and your phone's internal clock for later queries (for example, if you're needing a synchronised clock to assist in authentication). You could use a static member on one of your classes that returned your server's version of the date time, instead of using `DateTime.Now` throughout your code.